# Retrying reader in spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

I have written a spring batch application and item reader is throwing exception.
How do I retry item reader?
I h ave added 
`@EnableRetry` on application class and below is the reader code

```
@Bean
  @Retryable(include = { RuntimeException.class }, maxAttempts = 1000, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 0))
  public ItemReader<Student> reader() {
    return new InMemoryStudentReader();
  }
```

Below is the reader class

```
public class InMemoryStudentReader implements ItemReader<Student> {

  @Autowired
  private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

  private int nextStudentIndex;
  private List<Student> studentData;

  public InMemoryStudentReader() {
    initialize();
  }


  private void initialize() {
    Student s1 = new Student(1, "ABC");
    Student s2 = new Student(2, "DEF");
    Student s3 = new Student(3, "GHI");

    studentData = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(s1, s2,s3));
    nextStudentIndex = 0;
  }

  @Override
  public Student read() throws Exception {
    Student nextStudent = null;

    if (nextStudentIndex < studentData.size()) {
      int a =jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT id FROM val LIMIT 1", Integer.class);
      if(a == 2) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Exception");
      }
      nextStudent = studentData.get(nextStudentIndex);
      nextStudentIndex++;
    } else {
      nextStudentIndex = 0;
    }

    return nextStudent;
  }
}
```

But even after this the reader is not retried and job fails

Comment: Do you add `@EnableRetry`? Are you sure you're failing for RuntimeException? [docs](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-retry)

Comment: @WoAiNii I think its not working because of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38212471/springboot-retryable-not-retrying

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retry not working with Spring Batch with Java Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56170179/retry-not-working-with-spring-batch-with-java-config)

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I know faultTolerant is not applied to reader but I am specifically specifying Retryable on reader bean. It should be retried then

Comment: I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding `@Retryable` on a bean definition method. This method is only called at configuration time by Spring to create an instance of your bean and will unlikely fail.

You should be adding the annotation on the `read` method of your reader which is called at runtime when the step is running and might throw an exception:

```
@Override
@Retryable(include = { RuntimeException.class }, maxAttempts = 1000, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 0))
public Student read() throws Exception {
   ...
}
```

Comment: can we make JpaPagingItemReader retryable: public JpaPagingItemReader<DTO> reader(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaPagingItemReaderBuilder<DTO>()
                .name("Test")
                .entityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory)
                .queryString("query")
                .pageSize(chunkSize)
                .build();
    }