# StoredProcedureItemReader not able to Retry on deadlock exceptions

Tags: spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

I am having difficulty in getting my StoredProcedureItemReader to Retry once it fails due to deadock exception on the Database.
Here is the configuration for my step process:

```
@Bean    
public Step Step() throws Exception {       
            return stepBuilderFactory.get("Step")
                    .<Student, Student>chunk(100)
                    .reader(storedProcItemReader())
                    .processor(studentItemProcessor)
                    .writer(fileItemWriter())
                    .faultTolerant()
                    .retryLimit(5)
                    .retry(myException.class)
                    .backOffPolicy(backoffPolicy())
                    .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public StoredProcedureItemReader<Student> storedProcItemReader() throws Exception {
        return studentItemReader.getDataFromDatabase(dataSource);
    }
```

studentItemReader class file:

```
@Component
@StepScope
public class studentItemReader{

    @Retryable(include = {DataAccessException.class, JDBCException.class, TransactionException.class, DeadlockLoserDataAccessException.class, Exception.class }, maxAttempts = 5, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 1000,
            maxDelay = 15000, multiplier = 2))
    public StoredProcedureItemReader<Student> getDataFromDatabase(DataSource dataSource) {
        
            StoredProcedureItemReader<RegionResponse> reader = new StoredProcedureItemReader<>();
            
            SqlParameter[] parameter = { new SqlParameter("@studentId",
                    java.sql.Types.INTEGER) };
            PreparedStatementSetter statementValues = new PreparedStatementSetter() {
                @Override
                public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
                    ps.setInt(1, parameterValue);
                    }
            };
            reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
            reader.setProcedureName("dbo.StudentReport");
            reader.setParameters(parameter);
            reader.setPreparedStatementSetter(statementValues);
            reader.setRowMapper(new StudentRowMapper());
            return reader;
        }   
    }
}
```

So, the problem is I am not able to get the Retry piece working on my StoredProcedureItemReader after adding Retry on it. Please let me what mistake I am doing here. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding `@Retryable` on a method that returns an item reader. This method is only called at configuration time. If you want to retry a read operation at runtime whenever an exception is thrown, you should add the annotation on the `read` method of your reader. The annotation based approach of adding retry capabilities can be tricky, that's why I recommend the programmatic way to see where the actual retry is happening. Here is a quick example:

```
import org.springframework.batch.item.ExecutionContext;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.StoredProcedureItemReader;
import org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate;

public class RetryableItemReader<T> implements ItemStreamReader<T> {

    private final StoredProcedureItemReader<T> delegate;
    private final RetryTemplate retryTemplate;

    public RetryableItemReader(StoredProcedureItemReader<T> delegate, RetryTemplate retryTemplate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
        this.retryTemplate = retryTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public T read() throws Exception {
        return retryTemplate.execute(context -> delegate.read());
    }

    @Override
    public void open(ExecutionContext executionContext) throws ItemStreamException {
        delegate.open(executionContext);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(ExecutionContext executionContext) throws ItemStreamException {
        delegate.update(executionContext);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws ItemStreamException {
        delegate.close();
    }
}
```

Then you can use it as an item reader in your step:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public RetryableItemReader<Student> storedProcItemReader() {
    RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplateBuilder()
            // define your retry policy
            .build();
    StoredProcedureItemReader<Student> delegateItemReader = new StoredProcedureItemReaderBuilder<Student>()
            // define your delegate item reader
            .build();
    return new RetryableItemReader<>(delegateItemReader, retryTemplate);
}
```

Comment: I have added the code. Now I am getting `Caused by: org.springframework.batch.item.ReaderNotOpenException: Reader must be open before it can be read.` on `RetryableItemReader<T>` class. Can you tell please tell me how can I resolve that

Comment: I see, this is because the reader in my initial answer implements `ItemReader` and not `ItemStreamReader`. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Oops sorry. I thought I have accepted it a while back.